# Spinner Listener

Tags: android, android-spinner

У меня есть spinner на который я повесил setOnItemSelectedListener. Все работает, но проблема в том, что когда я программно выделяю элемент в spinner, то этот метод тоже срабатывает, а я хочу чтоб он срабатывал на изменения которые не программмные. Как я могу это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё очень просто. Убирайте слушатель перед программным выбором и сразу после назначайте обратно. Вот всевдокод:

```
spinner.setOnSelectListener(null);
spinner.select(0);
spinner.setOnSelectListener(listener);
```

Comment: хм, и правда...